# What are the abbreviations for days of the week?

Tags: word-choice, abbreviations, dates

I would like to know if there is a common abbreviation for days of the week in a two letter form.

I mean: Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday; can be abbreviated as Su, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa? Is this the common form?

Note that I have also seen Sn for Sunday, and some times St for Saturday (but I think less frequently).

It will be used in a tabular data program to show information about free work days of employed and each column can't have enought space to include full week day name.

For "common form" I mean, what are the abbreviations that is more used in programs.

Comment: Have you looked online?

Comment: I would say it's _a_ common form, but not _the_ common form.

Comment: @Kris Of course, but I have see many uses so I want to know if is a standard of what to use.

Comment: @J.R. and what is the common form?

Comment: Just start spelling the day, then quit when you're bored.

Comment: I've never seen Sn or St. I don't think there's a defined _standard_ set of abbreviations, just the commonly used one-, two- or three-letter abbreviations, plus some now less common longer ones (e.g. Thurs).

Comment: @PhoneixS: The [graphic](http://i.stack.imgur.com/okAcI.png) in JavaD's answer showed **two** common forms.

Comment: There is reasonable consistency between various lists on the web. The only real choice is whether you want to use 1,2 or 3-letter abbreviations. JR's comment points you to one list. See also http://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/time-days-of-week.htm, http://editingandwritingservices.com/Abbreviating-Months-and-days-of-the-Week/, http://www.esolcourses.com/uk-english/beginners-course/unit-3/days-of-the-week/days-of-the-week-matching.html, http://www.bydewey.com/monthdayabb.html

Comment: Also, look on a few English-language calendars.

Comment: OMG, this is **not** opinion-based. [Rolls eyes] OP specifically stated they were looking for *common* forms. Hence this is an objective question based on *statistics*, not opinion. σ_σ

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Three-letter abbreviations are more common, but two-letter ones are also fully understandable.

In a tabular calendar, even one-letter abbreviations are acceptable, since the position is sufficient to disambiguate the S's and T's.

Comment: So Su, Mo, Tu, We, Th, Fr, Sa is a common form and can be used without problem?

Comment: @PhoneixS: You haven't even said where you want to use the abbreviations, so it's hard for anyone to say definitively whether or not the two-letter forms could be used "without problem."

Comment: Ouch! True, sorry for my omission @J.R.

Comment: In the application you mention, two-letter abbreviations should be well-understood and work just fine. But really, this is more a question for the user than a question about English.

Answer (score 13):

Another variation I have seen (and used) is (starting with Sunday):
Su, M, Tu, W, Th, F, Sa

In other words, single letters for unambiguous days, two letters for the ambiguous ones.